# ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib CRC Error. How To Fix?

Tags: c#, sharpziplib

I'm using the library `ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib` to compress text. 
After the compress finish I convert to `base64 string` and store in database. When I need to know what's stored, I get the value from database and decompress.

But, only in one client computer, when I compress a text and try to decompress the following error is throw:

`BZip2 input stream crc error`

I don't know whats the cause of error, because in my computer all compress and decompress are working fine.
I need your help to know what's the cause of the error and how to fix it.  Sorry my bad english.

This is my code of compress and decompress:

```
        public static byte[] Compress(byte[] bytesToCompress)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            Stream s = new BZip2OutputStream(ms);
            s.Write(bytesToCompress, 0, bytesToCompress.Length);
            s.Close();
            return ms.ToArray();
        }

        public static string Compress(string stringToCompress, Encoding encoding)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(stringToCompress))
                return String.Empty;

            byte[] compressedData = Compress(encoding.GetBytes(stringToCompress));
            string strOut = Convert.ToBase64String(compressedData);

            return strOut;
        }

    public static string DeCompress(string stringToDecompress)
    {
        Encoding encoding = Encoding.Unicode;
        string outString;

        try
        {
            byte[] inArr = Convert.FromBase64String(stringToDecompress.Trim());
            outString = encoding.GetString(DeCompress(inArr));
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException nEx)
        {
            return nEx.Message;
        }

        return outString;
    }

    public static byte[] DeCompress(byte[] bytesToDecompress)
    {
        byte[] writeData = new byte[4096];
        Stream s2 = new BZip2InputStream(new MemoryStream(bytesToDecompress));
        MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream();
        while (true)
        {
            int size = s2.Read(writeData, 0, writeData.Length);
            if (size > 0)
            {
                outStream.Write(writeData, 0, size);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        s2.Close();
        byte[] outArr = outStream.ToArray();
        outStream.Close();
        return outArr;
    }
```

Comment: Please show which encoding do you use to get bytes from text and for decompression. Also decompress method code would be helpful.

Comment: @smiech I edit the question with the code. The encoding used is Unicode.

Comment: Does this happen on any text or a particular one? Where exactly is the exception thrown?

Comment: @smiech This trouble occours to a random text in random time. The exception is only this: `BZip2 input stream crc error`and haven't inner exceptions.

Comment: What is a sample string that causes the error? For the sample string, is the error repeatable?